# download from source storage.googleapis.com

Tags: curl, wget

I tried to download my report results from google API storage from code. I always get timeout.

After I tried to debug...

1. Tried to use wget, ... no success
2. Tried to use `curl`, ... no success

But everything works fine if I copy and paste the url to my browser.
I tried to google it up, and found an article here: https://source.android.com/source/downloading.html

Because this example also not working for me, seems to something wrong with https://storage.googleapis.com .

Can anybody fetch any response through command line from this source? If yes, please share the secret with me.

can somebody check the first step for me?

`$ curl https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/bin/repo
$ chmod a+x ~/bin/repo`

Comment: Solved, seems to be something was wrong with the google service.